# Animate an image sequence in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take a series of images captured from a webcam (jpgs) and animate them via OpenCV / Python. I know I can play back a pre-recorded video file via cv.CreateFileCapture and cv.QueryFrame, but how does this work with a folder of still images?

Comment: cv.LoadImage('path/to/image')

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do a `cvShowImage` and then a `cvWaitKey(delay)` in a loop and set delay to something appropriate for your desired framerate.

```
import glob
import opencv.highgui

highgui.cvNamedWindow('mahMovie')

# Assumes an ordered sequence of filenames (001.jpg, 002.jpg, etc)
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('./*.jpg')):
    img = highgui.cvLoadImage(filename)
    highgui.cvShowImage('mahMovie', img)
    highgui.cvWaitKey(33)

highgui.DestroyWindow('mahMovie)
```

Comment: Just add a tiny apostrophe one character before the end

Answer (score 1):

One way is to turn the sequence of images into an avi movie

```
writer = highgui.cvCreateVideoWriter('movie.avi', highgui.CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G'), framerate, (width,height))

for i in range(len(images)):
    highgui.cvWriteFrame(writer, images[i])


highgui.cvReleaseVideoWriter(writer)
```